# Extract words from a text that begin with a consonant and end in a vowel

Tags: text-processing

I have to make a Linux shell program to convert a text file into another text file that only contains words that start in a consonant and end up in a vowel, eliminating numbers and punctuation marks.

vowel=aoeui
consoants=bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz

It is to retain the format of the original text, it only removes words that do not meet the requirements (start in vowel and end in consonant), numbers and punctuation symbols.

I tried `grep`, or `sed`, but I can not come to any conclusions.

Comment: at least, post a fragment of your text file

Comment: It's an exercise, it's my choice of text.

Comment: What qualifies as a _vowel_ or _consonant_? Are `é`, `y`, `α` to be considered _vowels_?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas update question

Comment: Should it match on `Stéphane` even though it contains characters that are neither consonants nor vowels (but not numbers nor punctuation either) as per your definition?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes. Stéphane begins with a consonant and ends up in a vowel. That's what matters. If the text appears "Stéphane!" the end result should be "Stéphane"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
consonants=BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
vowels=AEIOUaeiou

< file tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' |
  grep -x "[$consonants].*[$vowels]"
```

Would report all the sequences of alphabetic characters (as classified as such in your locale) that start with one of those English consonants and end in one of the English vowels.

```
< file tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' |
  grep -x "[$consonants][$consonants$vowels]*[$vowels]"
```

Would restrict to those that contain only English letters (would not match on `Stéphane` as the `é` is not one of the *allowed* letters).

```
< file tr -cs "$consonants$vowel" '[\n*]' |
  grep -x "[$consonants].*[$vowels]"
```

Would ignore any character that is not one of those English letters (so would find `peri` and `dico` inside `periódico`).

(note that some `tr` implementations like GNU `tr` don't support multibyte characters so would choke on those ó/é characters anyway).

As an example, on a:

```
FooBar Fee123 foo-bar periódico
```

input, and in a typical en_US.UTF-8 locale on a FreeBSD system (one that has a POSIX `tr`), you'd get with the 3 solutions:

```
1            2           3

Fee          Fee         Fee
foo          foo         foo
periódico                peri
                         dico
```

Not that while none of them would match on `Blé` where the `é` is entered as a U+00E9 character, all would find `Ble` inside `Blé` where that `é` is `e` followed by U+0301 the combining acute accent (which is not an alphabetical character) and the first one wouldn't match on `Stéphane` written with the combining acute accent.

To work around that, you could use `perl` instead of `tr` in the first approach to also keep the combining marks before filtering with `grep`:

```
< file perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/[^\pL\pM]+/\n/g' |
  grep -x "[$consonants].*[$vowels]"
```

Or do everything in `perl`:

```
< file perl -Mopen=locale -lne 'print for
  grep /^[bcdfghj-np-tv-z].*[aeiou]$/i, /[\pL\pM]+/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -io '\<[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz][a-z]*[aeiou]\>'
```

Comment: It looks like the OP would like us to find `foo` inside `foo123`

Comment: Note that in typical GNU locales, it would match on `bze`, `býe`, but not `bźe` as `ź` comes after `z`.

Comment: Note that in Turkish GNU locales, it would not match on `FERRARI` as `grep -i i` only matches on `i` and `İ` there (not `I`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas An almost complete solution should probably involve a 500 lines Perl script that would normalize `LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH ACUTE ACCENT` to `Z`, and would handle combining characters. It would still fail in many cases.  I'm afraid I'm not motivated enough to write that in a SO post. _shrug_

Comment: Yes, I'm just adding those as _notes_. I suspect the OP can live with those limitations anyway, but it's worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
grep -oiw '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz][a-z]*[aeiou]'
```

The first *bracket expression* matches consonants, the second any letter a-z, and last vowels.

Comment: Thank you! I just do not understand the -w flag? Is it to parse each word with the defined regex?

Comment: With `-w` [*grep*](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Matching-Control.html#Matching-Control) will only match whole words.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out the needed words retaining the initial text formatting - **awk** solution:

Sample `textfile` contents:

```
Any delicate you how kindness horrible outlived servants. You high bed wish help call draw side. Girl quit if case mr sing as no have. At none neat am do over will. Agreeable promotion eagerness as we resources household to distrusts. Polite do object at passed it is. Small for ask shade water manor think men begin. 

He oppose at thrown desire of no. Announcing impression unaffected day his are unreserved indulgence. Him hard find read are you sang. Parlors visited noisier how explain pleased his see suppose. Do ashamed assured on related offence at equally totally. Use mile her whom they its. Kept hold an want as he bred of. Was dashwood landlord cheerful husbands two. Estate why theirs indeed him polite old settle though she. In as at regard easily narrow roused adieus. 

So delightful up dissimilar by unreserved it connection frequently. Do an high room so in paid. Up on cousin ye dinner should in. Sex stood tried walls manor truth shy and three his. Their to years so child truth. Honoured peculiar families sensible up likewise by on in.
```

---

The job:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '{ 
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
           if ($i~/^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][a-z]*[aoeui]$/) 
               printf "%s ",$i; print "" 
       }' textfile > newfile
```

---

The `newfile` contents:

```
delicate horrible case no none do we to Polite do shade 

He desire see Do mile he polite settle 

So Do so three to so sensible likewise
```

**----------**

To filter out the words each on separate line - **grep** solution:

```
grep -woi '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][a-z]*[aoeui]' oldfile > newfile
```

- `-w` (`--word-regexp`) - The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.

Comment: is it possible not to break the line for every word?

Comment: @user2989745, would you like to obtain all words on one single line?

Comment: Yes, keep the same order as the original text but only with the words resulting from grep.

Comment: grep -oiw '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz][a-z]*[aeiou]' input.txt | tr  '\n' ' ' : what do you think?

Comment: @user2989745, see my update for different purposes

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the solution with the awk command is case sensitive. and does not ignore punctuation symbols. Example: delicate. -> is rejected and should not be.

Comment: @user2989745, that's because you are changing your conditions on the fly. You have wrote ***end up** in a vowel* - that does not mean END UP with punctuation. I feel like I have wasted my help and time

Comment: The word ends in vowel, but may have a punctuation symbol to follow, as is normal. In these cases you must present the word without the punctuation symbol.

Comment: @user2989745, you **must** mention that conditions in your question to make it concrete and clear

Comment: "eliminating numbers and punctuation marks." This means that if you find a word that meets the requirements, followed by an end point has to be accepted. That's what I think, for the case "delicate." the expected result is: "delicate". I copied the problem statement in its entirety.